# Output elements from a string array to a sentence

Tags: python, string, list

The code should output string elements from list B when printing something from list A.

Say we have

```
text = ""
letters = ["a", "b", "c"]
names = ["Abby", "Bob", "Carl"]
```

How to iterate through the lists so when text is updated to

```
text = "a"
output: Abby

text = "ab"
output: "AbbyBob

text = "cab"
output: "CarlAbbyBob"
```

I have tried thinking about an if statement inside a foor loop but cannot really figure it out. I have simplified the problem to three elements for this post but the list has 30 elements, hence the for loop would be a good idea.

My try

```
text = ""

for i in text:
    if i == letters[letters ==i]:
        text = text + names[i]
```

Comment: Can you add whatever you tried so far?

Comment: What's your intended relationship between, e.g., "b" and "Bob"? Is it that Bob begins with the letter B, or is it that they are both the second element in their respective lists?

Comment: @tom - Yes, That is Bob starts with b

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Done that

Comment: In that case, use a dictionary, as the answers demonstrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Set up a dictionary:

```
thisdict =  {
  "a": "Abbey",
  "b": "Bob",
  "c": "Carl"
}
```

Then create a loop for your string

```
string= 'abc'
''.join(thisdict[char] for char in string)


>>>>AbbeyBobCarl
```

Comment: That is actually a nice solution, however I want the updated list to be a plain text. So list ['Abby', 'Bob', 'Carl'] should be AbbyBobCarl

Comment: I don't know why youd want a list at the end but if you just put list = ["".join(thisdict[char] for char in string)] you'll get a single element list

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dict to map letter to the name

```
letter_to_name = dict()

for idx, val in enumerate(letters):
    letter_to_name[val] = names[idx]

#Creates are mapping of letters to name

#whatever is the input text, just iterate over it and select the val for that key

output = ""
for l in text:
    if l not in letter_to_name:
        #Handle this case or continue
    else:
        output += letter_to_name[l]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dict to map one to the other, and then do concatenation:

```
dct = dict(zip(letters, names))  # {"a": "Abby", ...}
...
text = input()
output = ''.join(dct[char] for char in text)
print(output)
```

You could use a `for` loop here, but list comprehension is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = ['a', 'bc', 'cab', 'x']
letters = ["a", "b", "c"]
names = ["Abby", "Bob", "Carl"]

d = {k: v for k, v in zip(letters, names)}
s = [(t, ''.join(d[c] for c in t if c in d)) for t in text]

for l, t in s:
    print('text =', l)
    print('output:', t)
```

Prints:

```
text = a
output: Abby
text = bc
output: BobCarl
text = cab
output: CarlAbbyBob
text = x
output:
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do :

```py
output = ''.join([names[i] for r in text for i in [ letters.index(r)]])
# or output = ''.join([names[letters.index(r)] for r in text])
```

Gives :

```py
In [110]: letters = ["a", "b", "c"]
     ...: names = ["Abby", "Bob", "Carl"]
     ...:

In [111]: ''.join([names[i] for r in text for i in [ letters.index(r)]])
Out[111]: 'AbbyBobBob'
```